# Jquery click select image url instead of default input selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok guys here is what I have. Bellow is the jquery script which is supposed to accomplish, when I click the image thumbnail instead of opening the default input selector module it should retrieve that image url. Basically I want when I click the image thumbnail for that image to appear, just the same as if I clicked an input tag.

I managed to create a hidden input but now what I need is for when I click the image instead of opening the input upload, it should grab the full image from the src url `src="images/timeline9.jpg"`

Html

```
<ul class="thumbnails " style="margin:0px 0px 40px 5px;">
    <li class="fileupload-new thumber" style="width:31%; height:100px; margin:10px 15px 0px 0px;  ">

    <label for="fileUpload6" >
     <img src="images/timeline9.jpg"   id="imagebaner" height="100" width="100%" class="imageban1" ></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.fileUpload6').click(function(){
    $('.imageban1').select('src','images/timeline9.jpg');
      });
  });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use JSFiddle to show your code too much is missing will make it harder for people to help you.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle i created http://jsfiddle.net/qaYB2/ the images with inputs when you click it does the default select input. I want to make it so when I click any of teh image it will show the same as the default input select, but will fetch that image url

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you are using the select method as intended: http://api.jquery.com/select/

I would update the image source as follows:
$('.imageban1').attr('src','images/timeline9.jpg');

Comment: It is still reverting to the default select input method even with your code update. Please see the js fiddle jsfiddle.net/qaYB2